# BackBarButton text gets truncated after unhiding

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, navigationitem

When hiding and later unhiding the backButton (not a regular left/rightBarButtonItem) in the NavigationBar via `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true/false` the text gets truncated in the middle.

Set the Text Size (dynamic font size) of your phone to the smallest value (or second smallest) otherwise it doesn't work.

Example: The back button shows the title of the previous controller, e.g. `< Settings`. After hiding and showing it the back button again it now says `< Se...gs`

Is there any known workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop UIBarButtonItem text from truncating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144390/how-to-stop-uibarbuttonitem-text-from-truncating)

Comment: Unfortunately not as the issue is not related to UIBarButtonItems that I create but are created by the system (the back button item).

Comment: Oh, sorry! Check if this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600948/11974184

Comment: Maybe try setNeedsDisplay() after unhiding or setting the text again?

Comment: Thank you @TofuWarrior it does fix the issue! I have this issue in many places in one app and am wondering if a general fix that could be applied only once in the app does exist?

Comment: @benrudhart I'm facing the exact same issue, I couldn't figure out on which view did you call setNeedsDisplay() to fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anymore. I guess I'd try on the viewController owning the BarButtons or on it's navigationController